# Trying to position JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just learning javascript and I'm trying to center the theDate var by using the style tag but it stays to the far left anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```js
function initArray() {

  this.length = initArray.arguments.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    this[i + 1] = initArray.arguments[i];
}


var dayArray = new initArray("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

var monthArray = new initArray("januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december");

var nu = new Date();
var daily = dayArray[(nu.getDay() + 1)];
var day = nu.getDate();
var month = monthArray[(nu.getMonth() + 1)];
var jaar = nu.getYear();
var jaar4 = ((jaar < 1900) ? (jaar + 1900) : (jaar));

var theDate = (daily + ", " + day + " " + month + " " + jaar4);

document.write(theDate);
```

```css
#theDate {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Based on your CSS, you'll need to create an element with the ID "theDate" and append it to the document. Instead of `document.write()`, I recommend [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: Or you can have an elements in `html` at first hand and then enter values into it using `.innerHTML` . If the element is block-level than you content will be centered using `text-align: center;` or use `display: block; text-align: center;` if not block lvl element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css is centering the element with the id `theDate`, so wrap that string in a  with that id `document.write('<div id="theDate">' + theDate + '</div>');`

```html
<style type="text/css">
        #theDate {
          text-align: center;
          padding: 5%;
        }
        </style>

      <script type="text/javascript" id="theDate">

      function initArray() {

        this.length = initArray.arguments.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        this[i+1] = initArray.arguments[i];
      }
             

      var dayArray = new initArray("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

      var monthArray = new initArray("januari","februari","maart","april","mei","juni","juli", "augustus","september","oktober","november","december");

      var nu = new Date();
      var daily = dayArray[(nu.getDay()+1)];
      var day = nu.getDate();
      var month = monthArray[(nu.getMonth()+1)];
      var jaar = nu.getYear();
      var jaar4 = ((jaar < 1900) ? (jaar + 1900) : (jaar));

      var theDate = (daily + ", " + day + " " + month + " " + jaar4);

      document.write('<div id="theDate">' + theDate + '</div>');

      </script>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it perfectly!

Comment: Excellent! If this worked, please accept the answer so that others can also benefit in case of a similar issue. :)